# Not able to solve Plus One Java problem on Leetcode

Tags: java

I am trying to solve [Plus One on Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/plus-one/)

The description is as follows:

You are given a large integer represented as an integer array digits, where each digits[i] is the ith digit of the integer. The digits are ordered from most significant to least significant in left-to-right order. The large integer does not contain any leading 0's.

Increment the large integer by one and return the resulting array of digits.

Example 1:

Input: digits = [1,2,3]
Output: [1,2,4]
Explanation: The array represents the integer 123.
Incrementing by one gives 123 + 1 = 124.
Thus, the result should be [1,2,4].

My code is:

```
class Solution {
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    
    long temp=0;int c=0;
    for(int i:digits)
    {
        temp=temp*10+i;
        //System.out.println(temp);
        
    }
     //System.out.println(temp);
    temp+=1;
    //System.out.println(temp);
    long copy=temp;
    while(copy>0)
    {
        copy/=10;
        c++;
    }
    
    int[] result=new int[c];
    
    for(int i=c-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        //System.out.println((int)temp%10);
        result[i]=(int)temp%10;
       // System.out.println(result[i]);
        temp/=10;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

}

The problem is when I am trying to extract the number in the unit's digit it is givig 9 instead of 1.

Expected output:[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1]

My Output:[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,9]

Comment: instead of casting `temp%10` to an int grab that last digit first in a long `long thisDig = temp % 10` then cast it to an int before you save it `result[i] = (int)thisDig` the problem is the long is cast to an int and then divided, but your long is too large and doesn't appear correctly on the first loop iteration. Try printing `(int)temp` and see what you get

Comment: @Portal The LeetCode challenge states `1 <= digits.length <= 100`, so `long` is still way too short for the approach: `int[]` to number; increment; number to `int[]`. You'll have to use `java.math.BigInteger` instead. Although the idea of the challenge is to just start increasing digits individually from the last digit backwards as long as you still encounter `9`s, instead of converting it to a number.

Comment: How does this relate to `dsa` (did you read the usage description?)

Comment: Another pointless programming exercise that no one will ever do in a real job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing really wrong with your code...it just needs a little tweak.

The problem you are having is within the `for` loop that converts the incremented number held in `temp` to an int[] Array. Casting the `temp % 10` to an `int` as in `result[i] = (int) temp % 10;` is going to produce an undesirable result. `temp` is a long and therefore shouldn't be cast to `int` **until** is has finished its modulo calculation. So, the simple solution would be to wrap the equation within parentheses, for example:

```
result[i] = (int) (temp % 10);
```

That should solve the immediate problem. An even bigger problem is the fact that you are limited to a numerical value that can only fit into a `long` data type. An `int[]` Array can hold an extremely large number if you were to take each element of that array and sequentially combine the digits. A `long` data type for example can only hold an unsigned value of `9223372036854775807`. As you can see, this would create an int[] Array of 19 elements and that's a small Array.

What if the Array contained 100 elements (digits)? That's a pretty big number but not necessarily out of the realm of use. This is why you have been advised (in comments) to utilize the [java.math.BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class. With BigInteger, you can work with any size of **integer** number which is basically what you **really** need. Here is how you could carry out the same task using **BigInteger**:

```
public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
    java.math.BigInteger num = java.math.BigInteger.ZERO;

    // Convert int[] Array to a BigInteger number...
    for (int b : digits) {
        num = num.multiply(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(10))
                           .add(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(b));
    }

    // Add 1 to the determined BigInteger number
    num = num.add(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(1));

    // Convert BigInteger number back to an Array
    digits = num.toString().chars().map(c -> c - '0').toArray();

    return digits;
}
```

As an example, let's run this method against an `int[]` Array of 100 elements. That would be an integer number consisting of 100 digits. Now that's a **large** number:

```
/* Auto-create an int[] array containing 100 elements of random digits 
   0 to 9 (the first digit of the Array will never be a 0).   */
int[] array = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    int n = new java.util.Random().nextInt(9);
    // Make sure the first digit isn't a 0.
    if (i == 0 && n == 0) {
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    array[i] = new java.util.Random().nextInt(9);
}
System.out.println("Original: -> " + Arrays.toString(array));

/* Cycle the plusOne() method 12 times and display the array 
   within each cycle...                */
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    array = plusOne(array);
    // Display The array:
    System.out.println("Plus One: -> " + Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

The Console Window should display something like this. You will need to scroll to the end to see the incrementing (plus one):

```
Original: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 2, 6]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 2, 7]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 2, 8]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 2, 9]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 0]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 1]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 2]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 3]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 4]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 5]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 6]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 7]
Plus One: -> [7, 8, 8, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 8, 8, 0, 7, 5, 8, 1, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 4, 6, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2, 8, 3, 4, 3, 8, 3, 6, 2, 5, 6, 6, 3, 5, 1, 3, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 2, 4, 8, 5, 0, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 0, 5, 8, 8, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 5, 3, 8]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

I had one more doubt: Why is it that `(int)temp%10` giving me an undesirable answer for the digit in the unit's place but working for other other digits ?

Comment: The variable `temp` is a long data type. When `temp` is first used within the `for` loop for conversion to Array, it contains `9876543211`. This is too large of a value to be cast to `int` (max is: `2147483647`) but, once the next line of code is run: `temp/=10;`, this reduces temp to a value of (`987654321`) where it now can be cast to `int` - and no more problem. You don't want to cast temp to `int` anyways. You want to cast the result of the modulo calculation to `int`. This is why you wrap the formula (`temp%10`) in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward solution. Just what you do in the school: increment right to left with keeping carry for the next digit.

```java
class Solution {
    public int[] plusOne(int[] digits) {
        boolean carry = true;

        for (int i = digits.length - 1; carry && i >= 0; i--) {
            carry = digits[i] == 9;
            digits[i] = carry ? 0 : digits[i] + 1;
        }

        if (carry) {
            int[] tmp = new int[digits.length + 1];
            tmp[0] = 1;
            System.arraycopy(digits, 0, tmp, 1, digits.length);
            digits = tmp;
        }

        return digits;
    }
}
```